# Resize excel selection from a chosen cell to a specific range

Tags: excel, vba, resize, offset

I have data in range `B2:P10`.

If i select a cell (for example `C3`), what is the VBA code to select right to column "P" (so `C3:P3`)?

There is text in column "Q" so i cant select right to the 'end'.

I've tried using offset and resize functions but everything I try is relative and doesnt stop at the absolute of column "P".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming only a single cell selected:

```
Range(Selection, Cells(Selection.Row, "P").Select
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thought it would be a straightforward one just couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`selection.resize(1,14).select` if you'd like to start from your selected cell and resize your selected range or, to set the expanded range to a variable starting from `C3`, `set rngVariable = range("c3").resize(1,14)`.

Both will extend a single-cell selection along a single row from `C` through `P`, or 14 columns.